# passing 'float (float)' to parameter of incompatible type 'float'

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
//// PROTOTIPOS DE FUNCIONES

int numeroPagos(int anios);
// devuelve el numero de pagos mensuales

float interesMensual(float interesAnualTantoPorCiento);
// devuelve el interés mensual, correspondiente a un interés anual dado como tanto por ciento
// interesMensual=(1+interesAnual)^(1/12)-1

float pago(float capital, float interesMensual, int numeroPagos);
// devuelve la cuota mensual de la hipoteca 
// pago= capital x ((1+interés mensual)n x interés mensual) / ((1+interés mensual)n-1)
// n = numeroPagos

void leerCondicionesHipoteca(float * capital, float * interesAnualTantoPorCiento, int * anios);
// lee por teclado el capital, el interés anual (en %) y el número de años

//printTablaAmortizacion(float capital,float interesAnualTantoPorCiento,float anios);
// muestra la tabla de amortización de la hipoteca que incluye el pago mensual, los intereses
// el capital amortizado y el capital vivo
// intereses = capital vivo anterior * interés mensual
// amortizado = pago mensual – intereses
// capital vivo actual = capital vivo anterior - amortizado
//// IMPLEMENTACION FUNCION PRINCIPAL
int main()
{
  float capital,interesAnualTantoPorCiento;
  int anios;
  leerCondicionesHipoteca(&capital, &interesAnualTantoPorCiento, &anios);
  numeroPagos(anios);
  interesMensual(interesAnualTantoPorCiento);
  pago(capital, interesMensual, numeroPagos);

}
//// IMPLEMENTACION RESTANTES FUNCIONES
void leerCondicionesHipoteca(float * capital, float * interesAnualTantoPorCiento, int * anios)
{  
  printf("Introduce el capital: ");
  scanf("%f", capital);
  printf("Introduce el interes anual : ");
  scanf("%f", interesAnualTantoPorCiento);
  printf("Introduce el numero de anios: ");
  scanf("%d", anios);
}
int numeroPagos(int anios)
{
  return anios*12;
}
float interesMensual(float interesAnualTantoPorCiento)
{
  float n;
  n=(pow(1+interesAnualTantoPorCiento,((1/12)-1)));
  return n;
}
float pago(float capital, float interesMensual, int numeroPagos)
{
  float n,p,interes,anios;
  n=numeroPagos;
  interes=interesMensual+1;
  p= (capital *interes *n * interesMensual)/(interes*(n-1));
  printf("pago mensual: %f", p);
}
printTablaAmortizacion(float capital,float interesAnualTantoPorCiento,float anios)
{

}
```

I don't know what's the problem, I´m trying to use a function inside another one and it gives me this error:

> passing 'float (float)' to parameter of incompatible type 'float'

and I have to keep the functions like that, I can just change the inside part of them. So I have tried to put the function inside the other instead using in the main one function first and the other after

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] a good question and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: `float (float)` is a function type, not a `float`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to `pago()` should be the values returned from `numeroPagos()` and `interesMensual()`. You're passing the functions themselves.

```
int main()
{
  float capital,interesAnualTantoPorCiento;
  int anios;
  leerCondicionesHipoteca(&capital, &interesAnualTantoPorCiento, &anios);
  pago(capital, interesMensual(interesAnualTantoPorCiento), numeroPagos(anios));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice you're passing a function pointer instead of float value here:

```
pago(capital, interesMensual, numeroPagos);
```

Both `interesMensual` and `numeroPagos` are function pointers.